# Matlab GUI using GUIDE : Want to dynamically update graphs

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I've written a Matlab script that reads in data using a virtual COMM port in **real-time**. I've done a significant amount of signal processing in an mfile.

Next, I felt the need to have a compact GUI that displays the information as summary.

I only recently started digging and reading more of Matlab's built-in GUI tool, GUIDE. I've followed a few tutorials and am successfully able to get my graphs to display on my GUI **after a button-press**.

However, I want the **GUI to update in real-time**. My data vector is constantly updating (reading in data from the COMM port). I want the GUI to keep **updating the graphs** with the newer data, as opposed to relying on a button press for an update. Can someone please point me in the right direction for background updating?

Here is the relevant code currently for the GUI:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global data
global time

% Time domain plot
axes(handles.timeDomainPlot);
cla;
plot (time, data);
```

EDIT Changed code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%Setting it to display something when it ends
% t = timer('TimerFcn', 'timerOn=false; disp(''Updating GUI!'')',... 
t = timer(... 
            'TasksToExecute', 10, ... % Number of times to run the timer object
            'Period', 3, ...                
            'TimerFcn', GUIUpdate()); 

%Starting the timer
start(t)

function GUIUpdate()
global data
global time
%Parameters below axes
    global min
    global max 
      % Time domain plot
    axes(handles.timeDomainPlot);
    cla;
    plot (time, data);
    %Other parameters:
    set(handles.mean, 'String', mean);
    set(handles.max, 'String', max);
```

The error that I get is:

```
??? Error using ==> GUI_Learning>GUIUpdate
Too many output arguments.

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)GUI_Learning('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007385/getting-matlab-timer-to-update-matlab-guide-gui

Comment: @c0d3rz Check out this link about defining timerfcn callbacks http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-39541.html#f9-42494  Try setting 'timerfcn' to @GUIUpdate and changing GUIUpdate so that it has two inputs `GUIUpdate(obj, event)`.  'obj' will be the handle to the timer object and 'event' will have some details about how it was called.  By default timer function callbacks will be passed at least those two arguments.  I am not sure if that is the exact cause of your error but your sample does not look correct.  If I get a chance later today I will try to post an example timer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example using a timer with a timerFcn callback. I made a simple GUI with 1 axes and 1 button.

In the opening function I initialize the plot and create the timer.  In the start button callback I start the timer and start manipulating the data.  The timer function callback the just updates the y-data of the line via its handle.  Below are the relevant functions from the GUI's M-file (snipped init section and output fcn.

```
function testTimer_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
global y x
x = 0:.1:3*pi; % Make up some data and plot
y = sin(x);
handles.plot = plot(handles.axes1,x,y);
handles.timer = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate',...
                    'Period', 0.5,...
                    'TimerFcn', {@GUIUpdate,handles});
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in startButton.
function startButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global y x
start(handles.timer)
for i =1:30
   y = sin(x+i/10); 
   pause(1) 
end

function GUIUpdate(obj,event,handles)
global y 
set(handles.plot,'ydata',y);
```

You may want a Stop button to stop the timer depending on how your GUI is structured and were/how the data is updated.

Edit: Basic handles info some of this is pretty basic and you may already know it:

An individual handle to an object contains a bunch of properties that you can read with the get() function or set with the set() function.  So for example maybe I wanted to change the text of the startButton for some reason in my GUI.

```
set(handles.startButton,'String','Something Other Than Start');
```

You may just want to set a break point in your code somewhere (maybe in a button press) and play around with the handles struct.  Running `get()` commands on various objects to learn their properties.

Now the handles structure contains all of the ... umm... handles to your GUI's objects as well as any custom items that may be convenient for your to store there.  Most GUI callbacks automatically get passed the handles struct so you have easy access to all parts of the GUI.

Ex. The 'startButton' callback was automatically passed `handles`.  So I had easy access to the timer object via `handles.timer`.

Which brings me to sticking custom things into `handles`.  In the opening function I added a new item to the handles structure `handles.timer` and `handles.plot` because I knew they would be useful in other callbacks (like button press and the timerFcn callback).

However, to store these things permanently you need to use the 'guidata' function.  This function basically either stores the modified `handles` struct or retrieves a copy of `handles` depending on how you call it. So the following line in the opening function is storing the modified handles structure (added .timer and .plot) into the main GUI.

```
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Basically any time you add something in `handles` you should have that line to make the change permanent.

Now the other method of calling it is:

```
handles = guidata(hObject); %hObject can be any handle who is a child of the main GUI.
```

This will retrieve the handles structure for the GUI.

And last `handles.output = hObject` is just the default output when you launch your GUI.  IF you call your GUI via Matlab's command line like this `h = myGUI;`  it should return the handle to your GUI.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aero Energy. I think I've got to work how I wanted with your code help. I REALLY appreciate the help. I did read the timer help on the website, but couldn't really get it right, your code snippet really helped. It amazes me that you took out the time to write down relevant code to help me out. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please what these two lines of code do: 
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

Comment: I'm unsure of using this handles.* notation. I read the Matlab help file on using Handles, but it didn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: @c0d3rz See my edits above for a decent quick and dirty primer on GUI handles.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aero Energy. I would up vote your answer, but I don't have the min required reputation points ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [timer object](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bsy7gys.html). Set the callback to be the function that updates the plots.

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge. Is there a good reason you can't do it this way?

Comment: Can you please have a look at my Edit. I can't seem to properly use the timer function.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Making Graphs Responsive with Data Linking](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/data_analysis/brh7_h0-1.html)
 and the [linkdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linkdata.html) command.

> If the same variable appears in plots in multiple figures, you can
>   link any of the plots to the variable. You can use linked plots in
>   concert with Marking Up Graphs with Data Brushing, but also on their
>   own. Linking plots lets you
>
> - Make graphs respond to changes in variables in the base workspace or within a function
> - Make graphs respond when you change variables in the Variable Editor and Command Line
> - Modify variables through data brushing that affect different graphical representations of them at once
> - Create graphical "watch windows" for debugging purposes
>
> Watch windows are useful if you program in the MATLAB language. For
>   example, when refining a data processing algorithm to step through
>   your code, you can see graphs respond to changes in variables as a
>   function executes statements.

I made a quick and dirty test seen below and I am not sure how this will work in a GUI verses a function but may do the trick.

Note 1: I had to add a break point in my subroutine where it modifies the global `y` to actually see the plot auto-update.  You may need some combination of drawnow, pause, or a timer if data is getting changed rapidly.

```
function testLinking()
global x y
%Links failed if the global did not also exist in the base workspace
evalin('base','global x y');
x = 0:.1:3*pi; % Make up some data and plot
y = sin(x);

h = plot(x,y,'ydatasource','y','xdatasource','x');
linkdata on
testSub

function testSub()
%Test to see if a sub can make a linked global refresh
global x y
for i = 1:10
    %This should automatically update the plot.
    y = sin(x+i/10); 
end
```

Edit: there may be ways around the use of globals depending on how your functions are structured ... but I don't have time to dig into it to much.

Comment: Thanks Aero, however I wasn't clear in my question. Aside from changing the graphs, I also have a few static text boxes, that I want to update as well. It seems Timer is the way to go ...

Comment: @c0d3rz See My other answer for help with getting your timer to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback on the serial object that executes a plotting function. You must attach the callback to the 'BytesAvailableFcn' event on the object (see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f73779.html) for more details on the properties of the com object).

Essentially, when there are bytes available on the com port, you instruct matlab to run a specific function. In your case, it will be the function updating the GUI. If you need to process the incoming data first, then your callback function will first do the signal processing and then do the plotting commands.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, however I wasn't clear in my question. Aside from changing the graphs, I also have a few static text boxes, that I want to update as well. It seems Timer is the way to go ...

Comment: You could also update the boxes using get/set. The thing is, that i don't know the logic of your code.